# Changing values of objects in image opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

I've almost no experience in image processing, so please excuse me if my question will be somewhat obvious. But after searching on google and stackoverflow I still have no idea how to complete my task. 
What I want to do is convert matrix like in this image below:

[image]

I searched through grab-cut, mean-shift, canny edge detection, region growing and merging but I didnt see a way to implement them to solve my problem. I care about how fast will that method work, and all these above were looking rather complex and slow.

PS. Sorry for my poor english, but it's not my native language.

Comment: Probably using a funciton`cv::floodFill` is a way to go. First covert your all 1s to value meaning "not assigned" so something like 255. Then loop over ever pixel in your image and if its value is "not assigned" do a flood fill with `fill_value`. Increment `fill_value` after every `cv::floodFill` call.

Comment: Google for connected components labeling. And search examples on how to use cv::connectedComponents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like *"Connected Component"* or *"Blob Analysis"*, which would be a job for OpenCV's *"connectedComponents"* - thanks to @Miki. Basically you are finding blobs of connected white pixels (`1`s) on a black background (`0`s) and incrementing the label for each blob identified.

*"Labelling"* might be another search term for you.

Comment: Simple blob detector is for extracting blobs with almost equal intensity (plus eventually shape, size and other criteria) in a grayscale image. So it's not the right tool here. This is connected components labelling, and you can use cv::connectedComponents

Comment: Thank you very much Miki, it works!   
It's important to mention that background needs to be black (value = 0) or connectedComponents won't work properly.